# Restore the permissions modified by SetNamedSecurityInfoW (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi, permissions, acl

I'm trying to add and remove read/write permissions to a folder for a specific user (or group). It's fairly easy to add the "deny" permissions to the ACL, which serves the purpose, but trying to restore or delete pre-existing entries doesn't work.

```
bool modifyPermission(const std::wstring& path, const std::uint32_t permission, ACCESS_MODE accessMode, TRUSTEE_TYPE trustee, const wchar_t* trusteeName)
{
    const DWORD access = static_cast<DWORD>(permission);
    const DWORD inheritance = SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT;
    PACL acl = nullptr;
    bool status = GetNamedSecurityInfoW(path.c_str(), SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nullptr, nullptr, &acl, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return false;
    }
    EXPLICIT_ACCESSW accessEntry;
    ZeroMemory(&accessEntry, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESSW));
    accessEntry.grfAccessPermissions = access;
    accessEntry.grfAccessMode = accessMode;
    accessEntry.grfInheritance = inheritance;
    accessEntry.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_NAME;
    accessEntry.Trustee.TrusteeType = trustee;
    accessEntry.Trustee.ptstrName = const_cast<LPWCH>(trusteeName);
    PACL newAcl = nullptr;
    status = SetEntriesInAclW(1UL, &accessEntry, acl, &newAcl);
    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        LocalFree(acl);
        return false;
    }
    std::wstring mutableCopy = path;
    status = SetNamedSecurityInfoW(&mutableCopy[0], SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, nullptr, nullptr, newAcl, nullptr);
    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        LocalFree(newAcl);
        return false;
    }
    LocalFree(newAcl);
    return true;
}
```

Using the function this way, and it works as intended (Properties -> Advanced Security Settings):

`modifyPermission(LR"(D:\test)", 0xFFFFFFFF, DENY_ACCESS, TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP, L"Users");`
[image]

However, I can't seem to undo the changes. It doesn't matter if it's an iteration over ACL + `DeleteAce`, `AtlGetDacl/AtlSetDacl` from <atlsecurity.h>.

1. How do I delete the entries I've just added?
2. How important is it which user is running the application? If the folder is stripped of permissions, does that mean I cannot change the ACL?

Comment: _I can't seem to undo the changes_ Does the code that tries encounter an error condition?  If so, what is it?  (`GetLastError()`)  And indeed, show us that code please.

Comment: [DeleteAce](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/ac06e54a15e9a62443e400fffff190fb978ea586/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/fax/faxsecurity/cpp/FaxSecurity.cpp#L433) should work except there are some errors such as ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. *If the folder is stripped of permissions, does that mean I cannot change the ACL?* Yes, that's permissions. Also see [Order of ACEs in a DACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/order-of-aces-in-a-dacl).

Comment: Who's the user whom `modifyPermission` is running as? If the current user denies itself, there is no issue.